# Is there any way to authenticate Federated Logins and restrict to not allow anyone to login in AWS cognito userpool?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, federated-identity, idp, aws-userpools

I have created userpool and integrated 3rd party IdPs to login to my website.
I want only some specific users of that Idp(example SAML ADFS, google) should be able to login and not every user.
Like if google user tries to login than first it should be checked whether this user is in our user's list (like by checking email id) and if it matches than redirect that user to main page otherwise not allowed to login.

I want to if it is possible via cognito or not and if yes than what is solution.

Comment: Have you tried using post authentication lambda triggers?

Comment: Post authentication is triggered after authentication of users is done. Pre authentication trigger would be the solution I guess, but I need an lambda code example as it is not clear or I am unable to understand through AWS documentations